# My First App keeps crashing

Tags: android

I am trying out the tutorial at the android website but my app keeps on crashing when I try to click the send message. i have no programming experience or java knowledge. i have looked through the questions posted and realise that the problem could be with

**Logcat :**

```
"Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit 
activity class {com.kamalak.myfirstapp/com.kamalak.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity};
     have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"
```

but i look at my code and isnt it there!? can somebody pls tell me what is wrong with my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kamalak.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your activity with following

```
<activity
        android:name="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">

</activity>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: happy to help u. @user3475445

Answer (score 0):

you have just missed to Register your Activity in your manifest file. So it will be

```
<activity
    android:name="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">

</activity>
```

between `<application></application>` tag.

Remove this line

```
  <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value="com.kamalak.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
```

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: but why does does eclipse add that piece of code if it is not necessary and crashes the app!

Comment: and they even included the code in the android tutorial website.

Comment: Because you have given a meta data to your `DisplayMessageActivity` and register your `MainActivity` as a Parent Activity.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA honestly I don't understand the problem either. `parentActivityName` should specify the parent activity for API 16 and above and `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY` should be used for API 15 and below, right? And I used it this way without a problem.